# Need to ensure mysqldump does not create an empty dump file in a scheduled backup plan

Tags: mysql, batch-file, database-backups

I'm using mysqldump to backup my database onto a folder that is directly linked with google drive.

My batch file code is

```
ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

C:\"Program Files (x86)"\MySQL\"MySQL Workbench 6.0 CE"\mysqldump.exe --user=**** --password=**** --max_allowed_packet=1G --host=196.167.3.111 --port=3307 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE "test_sales_manager" > C:/Users/user/"Google Drive"/dumps/%fullstamp%.sql
```

I run this backup.bat file on task scheduler twice a day to back up my database.
Now i want to run this every hour, maybe remove the timestamp and let the file be overwritten, but i need to ensure that an empty dump file does not get created. Presently if the connection or the database server is down, there is an empty dump file getting created. How do i avoid that?

Comment: Dump to a temp file; if valid, keep; else, delete. Admittedly scripting on Windows is your pain point, but it's certainly doable (...but preferable & more portable in bash in linux/cygwin).

Comment: @michael_n i was hoping mysqldump itself has that check point to see whether the dump file is empty, doing it via windows script will be a pain, my last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the exit code from mysqldump, you can do this as follows

```
...
C:/..../mysqldump  .... %TEMP%/%fullstamp%.sql
IF %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 GOTO EXIT

COPY %TEMP/%fullstamp%.sql C:/Users/user/"Google Drive"/dumps/%fullstamp%.sql
...

:EXIT
REM DO NOTHING - Something Went Wrong!
```

For reference expect the following error codes (from client/mysqldump.c):

```
/* Exit codes */

#define EX_USAGE 1
#define EX_MYSQLERR 2
#define EX_CONSCHECK 3
#define EX_EOM 4
#define EX_EOF 5 /* ferror for output file was got */
#define EX_ILLEGAL_TABLE 6
```

Comment: thanks! sorry for the noob question, but how do i set the exit codes?  
I have changed the code as per your additions http://i.imgur.com/FlTADpW.png but i am getting the following error http://i.imgur.com/R6YIbOj.png

Comment: thanks, that bug is solved, but now getting a syntax error, could you help? http://i.imgur.com/kttyTo6.png

Comment: Turn ECHO back on to see where it's failing.